# XML-Mapping fail to load array if it is root element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using xml-mapping within my ruby on rails app.

I need to load xml files and parse those to objects using xml-mapping

xml example is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements type="array">
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
  ...
</elements>
```

and here is the ruby code

```
require 'xml/mapping'

class Macro; end

class Elements
  include XML::Mapping

  array_node :elements, "elements","element" :class => Element
end

class Element
  include XML::Mapping

  text_node :name, "name"
  text_node :description, "description"      
end
```

The problem is when I use `Elements.load_from_file("my.xml")` it doesn't load array, but if I add root node to xml it works.

this xml works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mynode>
<elements type="array">
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
  ...
</elements>
<mynode>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm the xml-mapping author)

The XPath expressions are always relative to the mapped class's base node in the XML tree, which is the "elements" element for the "Elements" class. So you mustn't include that name in XPath expressions in Elements's nodes. Just leave it out and the code should work:

```
class Elements
  include XML::Mapping

  array_node :elements, "element", :class => Element
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid XML contains only one root node. At least what the SAX parser in Java defines as valid, so it seems to be agreed upon.

Comment: in both cases there is only one root node, that is not the case, the problem is that there should be one more level